# extracting data from a file with awk

Tags: awk

I have a data set like below

```
first 0 1
first 1 2
first 2 3
second 0 1
second 1 2
second 2 3
third 0 1 
third 1 2
third 2 3
```

I need to check this file and extract the third columns for first, second and third and store them in different files.

The output files should contain:

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 9):

This is pretty straight forward `awk '{print $3>$1}' file` *i.e.* print the third field and redirect the output to the file, where the filename is the first field.

**Demo:**

```
$ ls 
file

$ awk '{print $3>$1}' file

$ ls
file  first  second  third

$ cat first
1
2
3

$ cat second 
1
2
3

$ cat third 
1
2
3
```

Comment: I have this data set as a file. how can i open a file and extract this values. I need to do all as a bash file.

Comment: Did you read my answer? I does what you asked, what do you mean open a file, use an editor (`emacs`, `vi`, `nano`, ect) or `cat` it.. what do you want to do? There is no such thing as a `bash` file, what do you mean?

Comment: +1 short and precise! @alibalador sudo_O's awk-oneliner just does what you want, if your file has not too much "first/second.." blocks. pls test it first.

Comment: sorry, I got it. can you help me how can I set the output file name and not based on the first column.

Comment: What do you want them based on? You should have included this in the question!

Comment: @sudo_O please modify the script to print the number I'm thinking of.

Comment: @EdMorton `awk 'BEGIN{print 404}'`?

Comment: Haven't tried this, but I think if you want different filenames than whatever shows up in the first column, you can do something like `BEGIN {filenames["first"] = "one"; filenames["second"]="two"; filenames["third"]="three"}` then in the main loop do `print $3>filenames[$1]`.